# Is there any limit for number of email templates that can be created?

Tags: email-template

Salesforce allows us to create custom email templates, Is there a limit for the number of email templates that can be created?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no limit to the number of email templates you can manage. There is no documentation that suggests there is any sort of limitation, and I've personally never encountered any limit. Any such limit would probably be here, [Salesforce Limits Quick Reference Guide](https://login.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf). There are limits to the size of each template, but no limit on the total number of templates you can create.

Answer (score -1):

There’s no limit on sending individual emails to contacts, leads, person accounts, and users in your organization directly from account, contact, lead, opportunity, case, campaign, or custom object pages.

Using the API or Apex, you can send single emails to a maximum of 1,000 external email addresses per day based on Greenwich Mean Time (GMT). Single emails sent using the Salesforce application don't count toward this limit. There’s no limit on sending individual emails to contacts, leads, person accounts, and users in your organization directly from account, contact, lead, opportunity, case, campaign, or custom object pages.

For further details regarding the email limits size and information you can just go through the following link as below:-
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_email_general.htm&language=en_US
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_email.htm

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you've misread the question.

Comment: The question OP has related to number of Email Templates can be created and not about number of Emails can be send.